# Cannot play the video

Tags: java, android

I am trying to play the video file .But it gives me error(1,-1004).I am not able to find what problem is .

Kindly help

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  VideoView videoView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        videoView= (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);

   videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.234/hls-live/livepkgr/_definst_/liveevent/livestream.m3u8"));
     videoView.start();  



}
}
```

Comment: try to run in real devicve this errar come in eemulater

Comment: I am running on real device

Answer (score 0):

// try this code

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  VideoView videoView;
  String VideoURL = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        videoView= (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view);

try {
       MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    MainActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoView);
           Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoView.setVideoURI(video);

         } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                videoView.start();
            }
        }); 



}
}
```

Comment: I cant play this specific link http://192.168.1.234/hls-live/livepkgr/_definst_/liveevent/livestream.m3u8"

Comment: You should to try using Vitamio(open source). It's an extension framework that does everything (and then some) that MediaPlayer does, including m3u8 streams.